# Removing indentation and carriage returns from XML returned by ASP.Net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

Hopefully someone can help with a seemingly simple problem.

I have written a basic web service which contains the following code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDocument SampleXML()
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml("<note><to>Foo</to><from>Bar</from><body>Test message.</body></note>");

        return doc;

    }
```

When I browse to the web service and view the source of the data returned, it's presented as follows in the browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Foo</to>
  <from>Bar</from>
  <body>Test message.</body>
</note>
```

I would like to see the XML produced as follows in its rawest form with no indentation or carriage returns, e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><note><to>Foo</to><from>Bar</from><body>Test message.</body></note>
```

Can anyone please advise how this can be achieved?  I have searched high and low but can't find anything which can help.  I am sure it will be something simple.

The reason for this is because when I parse the returned XML the carriage return and spaces are interpreted as additional nodes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use XmlWriter and then use setting Indent = false;

Comment: I am not certain how to do this, is XmlWriter something I can return or do I somehow need to intercept the XmlDocument that's returned by my SampleXML() method before it's sent to the browser?

Comment: XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = false;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("filename", settings);
            doc.WriteContentTo(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

Comment: Thank you.  This looks like it will need to save the file on the server - I need a way for the web service to return the data to the browser without the line breaks, any idea how I can achieve this please?

Comment: Try following :            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings(); 
            settings.Indent = false;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings); 
            doc.WriteContentTo(writer); 
            writer.Flush(); writer.Close();
            string xml = builder.ToString();

Comment: I haven't checked but it could be that the browser itself is doing the formatting. See if you can intercept the return before it hits the browser (step through and view via magnifying glass) - it might not be formatted (unless the viewer also formats it ??). Also, you haven't specified when/where/how you are parsing. You might be able to remove the carriage returns and spaces at that point, before parsing, or some other option. Plz add that info to your question.

Comment: I just did a little test and the result is as you want it (`doc.InnerXML` or doc.OuterXML`). So, *when* you want to deal with it does seem important.

Comment: Thanks both.  @wazz, it’s definitely not browser related as when you view the source it’s there in multiple browsers.  I’m parsing the response in the browser as my web service is used by an ajax call.The example above is primative but the real xml returned may be vast and it would be expensive to remove the carriage returns etc. in the browser via JavaScript.